# How to overcome issue regarding loading Notation package into Wolfram?

Tags: package, wolfram-mathematica, loading, notation

I'm trying to load a package 'Notation' into my Mathematica notebook, but it gives me some random error caused by Join function. What should I do? I tried to reinstall but it did not help.

Best,
Samuli

[image: Here's the output of the command <<Notation`]

PS. Other students have also this issue, but we haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: Confirmed on 12.3 on OS X.  You should inform support@wolfram.com . If the palette still functions ok you could suppress the error messages with ```Quiet[<<Notation`]```.  Could also ask on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See if [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250033/9490) helps

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should contact Wolfram Support.